# Rstudio / VS code addins on to suggest the name of package for each function

Tags: r, rstudio, vscode-extensions

I would like to explicitly use the package name in front of each function in an R script; for example, I need to use `dplyr::mutate` instead of just `mutate`.

Is it possible to check for this using an RStudio addins or VS code extension (and probably suggest the name of the package). This is similar to some functionalities of lintR.

A similar functionality exists when writing my own R package. Is it possible to check for that on a regular R script?

Comment: `conflicted` package comes to mind. https://conflicted.r-lib.org/